# How to populate serialize attributes in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following class

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize: bar
end
```

Its supposed to contain a list of flowers (say lily, jasmine). What format should I use to store this information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array

```
Foo.new.bar = %w(lilly jasmine)
```

Or any kind of object that can by serialized through YAML, check out [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class)